# migrating login-module configuration from JBoss 4.2 to Wildfly 9

Tags: jboss, wildfly, jboss-4.2.x, wildfly-9

We are migrating code from  JBoss 4.2 GA to Wildfly 9.0.2 now. I got some trouble on migrating login-module properties files, and need help.

We have an application that uses the login-module, which has configuration like:

```
<application-policy name="staticcontent">
    <authentication>
        <login-module  code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"                flag="required">
      <module-option name="usersProperties">staticcontent-users.properties</module-option>
      <module-option name="rolesProperties">staticcontent-roles.properties</module-option>
         </login-module>
    </authentication>
</application-policy>
```

Now migrating to WildFly, we are using standalone mode, I put these two property files under `/opt/jboss/standalone/configuration/`, and add configuration to `standalone.xml` like:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
        <security-domains>
            <security-domain name="my-auth">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/staticcontent-users.properties"/>
                        <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/staticcontent-roles.properties"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
           ......
```

When I deploy the application (called `content.war`, it is explored directory), I get the following error:

```
11:47:32,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDS0004: Found content. war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called content.war.dodeploy
11:48:14,095 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "content.war" (runtime-name: "content.war")
11:48:16,980 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "content.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./content.UndertowDeploymentInfoService is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.staticcontent]"]}
11:48:17,034 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "content.war" (runtime-name : "content.war")
11:48:17,035 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1)     WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0184:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.security.security-domain.staticcontent (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./content.UndertowDeploymentInfoService]
```

I'm not sure what this error message means. Can anyone help me? Thanks, Helen.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks TT who editted my questions making it more clear.

I got answer from a jboss master. In my configuration

```
<security-domain name="my-auth">
```

should be

```
<security-domain name="staticcontent">
```